# Authenticating into Firebase Realtime Database from Google Assistant App

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I’ve created a Google Assistant app with API.ai. I want to allow users of the app to be able to authenticate into my firebase real-time database. I've already set up implicit account linking and I can see my access token when I test the app. How would I set up an OAuth 2.0 token exchange endpoint to handle my access token. I already set up an empty Firebase function to handle the token but I’m unsure what to put in it. What's my next step for authentication?

Here’s a code snippet I found in the docs to verify idTokens but it doesn’t work with the access token I get after doing the account linking.

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
```

Would it be easier to get the current user's email so I could just look up the current user's uid?

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
```

Comment: When you say you have "setup implicit account linking", can you specify what you've done? Is that just an admin action you've taken, or do you have any code endpoints for the token exchange?

Comment: Sure! Here's a link to the docs that explains it. https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow

Comment: I understand the implicit flow. {: Are you saying you've implemented the endpoints as discussed in that document? Or is that your question?

Comment: Oh ok sorry the question wasn't clear. No I havent set up the endpoints. Yep that's my question!

Comment: Can you provide additional details about where the access token is coming from when you test the app and how you're testing the app without the endpoints setup? (What steps are you taking, what are you seeing, etc.)

Comment: I put all the information in the account linking section of the console (https://www.dropbox.com/s/erw8qz61k2f0bkq/implicit.png?dl=0). The response when I run the simulator is "It looks like your {My App Name} account is not linked yet". When I go to the debug info there's a link that to an oauth screen.
 (https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=my-app_dev&scopes=email+profile&return_url=https://www.google.com/).  After I sign in to my google account it redirects with a url (https://www.google.com/?result_code=SUCCESS&result_message=Accounts+now+linked.).

Comment: @Prisoner is that what you were looking for?